# How to pass this from one function to another function in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this

I have the current block of code:

```
cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
})

let turn = 0;

function clickHandler() {
  alternateTurn(this).bind(this);
// do more things here
}

function alternateTurn() {
  if(turn % 2 === 0) {
    this.innerHTML = 'X';
    this.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'Y';
    this.style.color = 'blue';
  }
    turn++;
    this.classList.add('decoration');
}
```

Now I want to pass the context of `this` from the clickHandler function to the alternateTurn function.

1. How do I do that? I see answers on here that says I should use `call` or `apply`. But `call` and `apply` are used when I want to call the second function immediately. However, in this case, do I need to call it immediately?
2. Once I pass in `this` from the clickHandler function, how do I invoke it in the second function?

Answer (score 0):

Well `call` and `apply` call it immediately and `bind` returns the function with the `this` binding, in you case seems like you just need to call it immediately with `call` or `apply`:

```js
cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
})

function clickHandler() {
  alternateTurn.call(this);
}

function alternateTurn(e) {
  console.log(e.target, 'that')
  if(turn % 2 === 0) {
    this.innerHTML = 'X';
    this.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'Y';
    this.style.color = 'blue';
  }
    turn++;
    this.classList.add('decoration');
}
```

However if possible, it might be easier to call `alternateTurn` directly. What you have here is a pattern called `pass-through method` where the method serves no purpose other than calling another method which does the exact same thing.

This is not really recommended, but your code might do more things :)

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't specific. Yes, the clickHandler() function does do more things, but I haven't written them yet. So in this case, how do I use `this` in the new function to change the `innerHTML`?

Comment: What do you mean? By using call, the function will be with the this passed,  and you'll be able to simply access it